# WPF Button Composed of Two TextBlocks Leaves Non-Clickable Area

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've created a button composed of two WPF TextBlocks. I have added a margin to the second TextBlock to space it from the first and both TextBlocks are contained within a StackPanel.

The issue is the blank space (the left margin of the second TextBlock) is not responding to a click. I would like not only the TextBlocks to be clickable, but also the blank space between them.

Here is the code

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 20 20 0" Command="{Binding OpenSideMenuCommand}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xf0c9;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" 
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeXXLarge}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="Menu" Margin="30 0 0 0" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeXXLarge}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

And here is the result

[image: Non-clickable area]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason you can't click on a panel when it's "empty".

One way to get around this is to set its `Background` property, e.g.:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 20 20 0" Command="{Binding OpenSideMenuCommand}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
    <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xf0c9;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" 
                                    FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeXXLarge}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="Menu" Margin="30 0 0 0" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeXXLarge}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: What a truly simple solution.  Thanks!